# MySQL syntax error - obvious?

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

Can anyone spot the syntax error in this thing?

```
UPDATE `inventory` 
LEFT JOIN `manufacturers` ON (
  `man_id` = `manufacturers`.`id`
)
LEFT JOIN `meta_tags` ON (
  `meta_tags`.`page_url` = REPLACE(REPLACE(`manufacturers`.`title`, " ", "_"), "\", "_")
)
SET `inventory`.`tag_ids` = CONCAT_WS("," `tag_ids`, `tag_id`)
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`tag_id`, `tag_ids`) = 0
```

Error message:

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
 check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
 version for the right syntax to use near 
 '_" ) ) SET `inventory`.`tag_ids` = CONCAT_WS("," `tag_'
```

Comment: Aren't strings quoted using a single quote? Or is that just in TSQL?

Comment: It doesn't matter in MYSQL, I don't know about standard / TSQL

Comment: Unless you `SET SQL_MODE='ANSI_QUOTES'` so it treats double-quote as identifier delimiters and only single-quote as string delimiters.  That's standard SQL behavior, and how it works in most brands of RDBMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to escape the `\` in your outer `REPLACE()` function. Try using

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(`manufacturers`.`title`, " ", "_"), "\\", "_")
```

in place of what you have. [Here's the MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-syntax.html#character-escape-sequences) explaining character escape sequences.

Comment: Hmm, that didn't do it.  Thanks for the suggestion, though.  (Of course, it's entirely possible that there was more than one issue)

Comment: @SamDufel: Hmph. That's the only syntax problem I can see; even the SO syntax highlighter catches it by coloring parts of the SQL incorrectly. EDIT: Ahh! a missing comma in `CONCAT_WS()` as well.

Answer (score 3):

Also

```
CONCAT_WS("," `tag_ids`, `tag_id`)
```

should be

```
CONCAT_WS(",", `tag_ids`, `tag_id`)
```

(missing comma)